# Inconsistency in balancing of the equation for lead sulfide oxidation by ozone

Tags: redox

The following question was asked in JEE Examination :
$\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{PbS}$ is oxidized by $X\ \pu{mol}$ of $\ce{O3}$ to get $Y\ \pu{mol}$ of $\ce{O2}$ :

The answer to which is given as 8.

If I balance the equation $\ce{PbS + $X$ O3 -> $Z$ PbSO_4 + $Y$ O2}$ by pure observation I seem to get the answer:

$\ce{PbS +2 O3 -> PbSO4 + O2}$

Thereby $X=2$, and $Y=1$

However, upon using the Ion electron method for balancing the former answer(=8) seems to uphold.

Hence, I was hoping that anyone could help me point out what part I'm overlooking.
TIA for any valuable insights.

Comment: Note that titles of both your and the other question suffer by the lack of information.

Comment: Chem+Math MathJax formatting:
 [Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/) / [Upright vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) 
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Not exactly, can you please elaborate on why I'm getting two different answers, is it informative that 4 ozone molecules should be required to react with PbS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assumption in $\ce{PbS + 2O3⟶PbSO4 + O2}$ is that *each ozone molecule contributes **two** oxygen atoms*. Consider that a simplified path for ozone decomposition is $\ce{O3 -> O2 + O^*}$ (though it is [far more complex than that](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4427716/)). In that scenario, each ozone molecule contributes only one oxygen to the reaction, while the other two wander away as $\ce{O2}$. Thus, you'd need twice as much ozone.

Also consider that *all* oxygen in ozone could be used in the oxidation of $\ce{PbS}$, depending on temperature, so this is *not* a good test question unless temperature is specified. Sulfide ores (or sulphides, as found in UK), have been [roasted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roasting_(metallurgy)) in air to release all the sulfur as $\ce{SO2}$, instead.

Comment: The reaction with ozone is different from the reaction with O2. This illustrates the importance of lab work to ascertain what actually happens. The simple equation is a composite of 2 equations:  reaction with ozone and subsequent reaction with O2. However, O2 seems to be incapable of oxidizing S= to sulfate so the reaction is not happening with O3 present. Limited ozone might give a mix of sulfate and PbO + SO2 It is very possible to write perfectly balanced equations with not even a toehold in reality.

Answer (score 2):

You can write this in many ways:

$\ce{PbS +4/3 O3 -> PbSO4 + no O2}$

$\ce{PbS + 2 O3 -> PbSO4 + O2}$

$\ce{PbS + 8/3 O3 -> PbSO4 + 2 O2}$

$\ce{PbS + 10/3 O3 -> PbSO4 + 3 O2}$

$\ce{PbS + 4 O3 -> PbSO4 + 4 O2}$

The reason is that you are combining two independent reactions:

$\ce{3 PbS + 4 O3 -> 3 PbSO4 }$

and

$\ce{2 O3 -> 3 O2 }$

In these cases, you need one other bit of information (such as the ratio of ozone reacting to dioxygen formed) to do stoichiometric calculations.

Comment: The reaction that is being combined is one that does not happen, the oxidation of sulfide or sulfur to sulfate by molecular O2. That reaction is the reaction limiting in sulfuric acid production needing catalysis by nitric oxides or vanadium oxide.

Answer (score 0):

The oxidation of $\ce{PbS}$ requires $4$ times $1$ atom oxygen, according to Dr Moishe Pippik. As each molecule ozone produces only one useful oxygen atom, it is reasonable to think that $4$ molecules $\ce{O3}$ are needed to produce $1$ $\ce{PbSO4}$. In this case the oxidation of $\ce{PbS}$ into $\ce{PbSO4}$ occurs according to : $$\ce{PbS + 4 O3 -> PbSO4 + 4 O2}$$

Comment: What would happen were O3 were limited?

Comment: Ij th amount of available ozone is limited, the amount of $\ce{PbS}$ being oxidized would be rather low.

Comment: I would think that the O2 formed might oxidize PbS to PbO and SO2 No? My point is that they are two independent reactions, possibly different conditions.

Comment: Well. I start from Poutnik's hypothesize stating that 1 $\ce{O3}$ produces only one useful oxygen atom, plus one $\ce{O2}$ molecule. It is also Kristen's last proposition. I don't really know if this hypothesis makes sense.